# Передать структуру данных от клиента к серверу

Tags: delphi, tcp

Здравствуйте. Вопрос следующий: как, пользуясь компонентами Indy TCP Server/Client можно передать структуру данных от клиента к серверу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разработайте свой протокол (сериализацию и десериализацию данных) по передаче даных. или же можно воспользоватся готовыми решениями. Например преобразовывать объекты в JSON строку и обмениватся строками.

Comment: Дело в том, что столкнулся в отсутствием Recv у IndyTCP Server в последних версиях Delphi :( В Delphi 7 recv присутствует (

Comment: Решил проблему, отказавшись от Indy компонентов, пользуюсь TCPClient/TCPServer, передаю чисто данные, получаю через ReceiveBuf и устанавливаю в качестве указателя на структуру первый байт данных

Comment: метод recv есть. Просто он немножко "припрятан". Со стороны клиента существует одно подключение, а вот со стороны сервера - много. И если просто сказать "recv", то откудова читать? Почитайте доки внимательнее.